# Web scraper for Yell

Tags: vba, web-scraping

I have created a scraper for yell.com in vba. The scraper is efficient enough to pull data from that site, whatever the search parameter is. If any link from that site is given to my parser, it is able to scrape the whole records irrespective of how many pages it has spread across. There is no "a" tag for the first page in pagination option for this reason it was previously scraping all the records except for the first page. However, I've fixed that issue and now it is working flawlessly pulling all the records available there. I tried to make it accurate yet there are always rooms for improvement.

```
Sub Yell_parser()
Const mlink = "https://www.yell.com"
Dim http As New XMLHTTP60
Dim html As New HTMLDocument, html2 As New HTMLDocument
Dim page As Object, newlink As String
Dim I As Long, x As Long

With http
    .Open "GET", "https://www.yell.com/ucs/UcsSearchAction.do?keywords=coffee&location=United+Kingdom&scrambleSeed=1370600159", False
    .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36"
    .send
    html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
End With

Set page = html.getElementsByClassName("row pagination")(0).getElementsByTagName("a")

' First page first, selected already, 'row pagination' doesn't have 'a' for it
GetPageData x, html

For I = 0 To page.Length - 2
    newlink = mlink & Replace(page(I).href, "about:", "")
    With http
        .Open "GET", newlink, False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36"
        .send
        html2.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    ' Next pages start from here

    GetPageData x, html2
Next I
End Sub

Sub GetPageData(ByRef x, ByRef html As HTMLDocument)
    Dim post As HTMLHtmlElement
    For Each post In html.getElementsByClassName("js-LocalBusiness")
        x = x + 1
        With post.getElementsByClassName("row businessCapsule--title")(0).getElementsByTagName("a")
            If .Length Then Cells(x + 1, 1) = .item(0).innerText
        End With
        With post.getElementsByClassName("col-sm-10 col-md-11 col-lg-12 businessCapsule--address")(0).getElementsByTagName("span")
            If .Length > 1 Then Cells(x + 1, 2) = .item(1).innerText
        End With
        With post.getElementsByClassName("col-sm-10 col-md-11 col-lg-12 businessCapsule--address")(0).getElementsByTagName("span")
            If .Length > 2 Then Cells(x + 1, 3) = .item(2).innerText
        End With
        With post.getElementsByClassName("col-sm-10 col-md-11 col-lg-12 businessCapsule--address")(0).getElementsByTagName("span")
            If .Length > 3 Then Cells(x + 1, 4) = .item(3).innerText
        End With
        With post.getElementsByClassName("businessCapsule--tel")
            If .Length > 1 Then Cells(x + 1, 5) = .item(1).innerText
        End With
    Next post
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would focus on the following improvements:

- *avoid code duplication* - for instance, you have the User-Agent string specified twice - extract it as a constant and re-use. `GetPageData` also has duplicated code
- some of your locators are layout-oriented which makes them less reliable and less readable - Bootstrap classes like `col-lg-12` or `col-md-11` have a layout/design meaning and have a high probability of change. `row businessCapsule--title` can become `businessCapsule--title`; `col-sm-10 col-md-11 col-lg-12 businessCapsule--address` would become `businessCapsule--address`.

Comment: @SMth80 right, leaving a single class name `businessCapsule--address` would do the trick. Thanks.

Comment: @SMth80 unfortunately, VBA bindings are very short on selenium-specific features that are available in other language bindings..do you have to use VBA?..

Comment: Thanks sir alecxe, for your review and suggestion. Basically, I just checked and noticed that selecting single class makes the script look better and brings the same result. Btw, is there any hard and fast rule concerning which one to choose as the best fit among compound classes?

Comment: @SMth80 other selenium bindings actually don't allow to specify compound classes in the "by class name" locators..try to use single data-oriented classes for a "class name" choice. Thanks.